# Cypress: each with internal promise - break loop

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, each, cypress

I'm using Cypress and I want to to exit from a each loop that contains a promise.

```
cy.get('div').find('div.myclass').each(el => {
    cy.get(el).find('span#myclass').then(span => {
        const myText = Cypress.$(span).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
        if (myText === 'somethings') {                
            cy.get(el).as('mySection');
            // ### HERE I WANT TO EXIT ###
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `return false` to break early, see [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Return-early).

> Return early
> You can stop the .each() loop early by returning false in the callback function.

**Tested with [cypress fiddle](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-fiddle)**

```js
const selectMySection = {
  html: `
    <div class="myclass">
      <span id="myid">
        <p>child of span1</p>
        <p>child of span2</p>
        span text - find this
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="myclass">
      <span id="myid">
        <p>child of span3</p>
        <p>child of span4</p>
        span text - ignore this
      </span>
    </div>
  `,
  test: `
    cy.get('div.myclass span#myid')
      .each(($span, i) => {
        console.log('processing span #', i); // only logs 'processing span # 0'
        const text = Cypress.$($span).text()
        if (text.includes('span text - find this')) {
          cy.wrap($span)
            .parent('div.myclass')  // move to parent
            .as('mySection')
          return false;
        }
      })

    cy.get('@mySection')
      .then(x => console.log(x))
  `
}
it('test selectMySection', () => {
  cy.runExample(selectMySection)
})
```

---

An alternative to looping is to use `.contains('my text')` to target the text you want.
Note that `.contains()` does a partial match, so you can ignore child texts.

```
cy.get('div.myclass span#myid')
  .contains('span text - find this')
  .as('mySection')
```

Comment: Technically, you need to alias the `div.myclass` not the span.

Comment: Maybe `cy.wrap($span).parent().as('mySection')`?

Comment: Thanks @MarionMorrison, I did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return false` at the end and you will exit the function.

```
cy.get('div').find('div.myclass').each(el => {
  cy.get(el).find('span#myclass').then(span => {
    const myText = Cypress.$(span).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
    if (myText === 'somethings') {
      cy.get(el).as('mySection')
      return false
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, with the return I only exit from the promise but I want to exit from the each! I want to break the loop! Thank you!

Comment: The `return false` will only work when the `if`statement is executed.

Comment: The if statement is executed because the alias has been set.

Comment: It still loops multiple times. Why remove the alias, that seems to be the goal of the code?

Comment: The only way I see it working is if you 'back-flip'. i.e set a variable defined in the each block scope and return it after the if.